# Testing REST API with nested object creation and endpoint transactionality

Tags: java, design, web-development, testing, rest

I'm building a location based REST API using Spring Boot, and I have run into a bit of a testing philosophy question. I have an object called `Location` that, among other things, requires a Google Places id to function. I've exposed the CRUD of this resource at `/locations` which delegates its work to `LocationService.createLocation`.

This class throws exceptions if 1). the GooglePlacesId doesn't exist or 2). if it isn't valid (not recognized on google places) or 3). the placeId already exists on saved `Location`. The `GooglePlacesService` is a dependency of the `LocationService` and handles communication with Google's api. Spring Boot allows for testing of your REST API directly with a mock web server and container thru `MockMvc`. When testing the location API, I mock out the googleService to allow me to test 2, and 1 and 3 are straightforward to test with how I seed the database or craft the payload.

So here's where I'm at a crossroads. There's another object `Post` to which a Location has a one to many relationship. A location shouldn't exist if it has no posts. So, if I'm creating a post for a `Location` that doesn't exist, and I use the `/locations` endpoint to create the location, I'm unable to transactionally create the location with the post. This would result in complex client error handling and object cleanup or some sort of running task that cleans up locations that are created with subsequent failures of the post creation. Would you recommend using this approach instead of allowing nested object creation?

The alternative I've gone for is allowing a location to be created through the `/posts` endpoint. This endpoint delegates to `LocationService.createLocation` for the embedded Location creation before creating the Post. This provides the necessary transactionality and simplifies client code. Have a broken a separation of concerns here?

As I am testing this endpoint, criteria 1-3 still apply for the nested Locations creation. What is the better testing approach: mocking the `LocationService` here and simply making sure this endpoint properly handles all exceptions thrown or actually crafting the payloads the same as in the testing of the `/locations` endpoint and creating true integration tests? The second seems like more work and duplication of testing. At the same time, criteria 1-3 are also all criteria of this endpoint and by creating true tests for them, I'm ensuring that these requirements are codified into this test. I'm also not fixing my test to the specific implementation of the `PostService` that happens to use the `LocationService` right now.

It's definitely not black and white, but I'm sure there's some compelling arguments for one direction

Comment: But if you go through `/posts` instead of `/locations`, there's no reason to keep `/locations` as an entry point for creationg Locations, right? Why would there be *duplication of testing* then?

Comment: @guillaume31 true, in this exact case i no longer duplicate. But I have encountered similar scenarios where I would want both endpoints and I'm generally unsure what the right choice here is (if there even is one).

Comment: I suggest you strip your Q from all unnecessary details and boil it down to that simple question then... and maybe provide schemas/diagrams to make it even clearer.